# Mysql C language api connect to database error

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I use [Mysql C language API](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/) connect to mysql 8.0.36 on Ubuntu 22.04 report an error

```
Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

This my `main.c`

```
int main() {
    MYSQL *conn;
    const char *server = "localhost";
    //const char *server = "127.0.0.1";
    const char *user = "test";
    const char *password = "password";
    const char *database = "test1";
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to database: Error: %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(untitled C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(THIRD_PARTY_DIR "/root/connector")
include_directories(${THIRD_PARTY_DIR}/include)
add_executable(untitled main.c)
target_link_libraries(untitled ${THIRD_PARTY_DIR}/lib/libmysqlclient.so)
```

I can use the command line and python contact to MySQL.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="test",
  password="password",
  database="test1"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

Comment: `ls /tmp/` don't find mysql.sock ` sudo find / -type s -name mysql.sock` also none.

Comment: I thin the cmake file is error,because i use the command ' gcc -o main main.c `mysql_config --cflags --libs`' to compile success! but i still don't know what's wrong with the cmake file